# Putting a Button Into A Table

Tags: php, html, button, html-table

I am struggling to make a button appear in my table. I have seen various other answers on here but are a little too complicated for me (i.e. use Javascript or are seeking to remove things from and to a database).

My code is below and its the 8th line I am having trouble with (the table works fine without that line) - just says 'unexpected '<'?

All I am seeking to do is show a button which will link to another website. That website is dictated by the variable 'book' which I pull from a database.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['traction']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['start']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['end']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['fare1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['fare2']."</td>";
echo "<td>".<input type="button" value="Book" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.".$row['book']'>."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['atoc']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code.. You need to close the quotes properly

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['traction']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['start']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['end']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['fare1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['fare2']."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<input type='button' value='Book' onClick=window.location.href='http://www.".$row['book']."'></td>";
echo "<td>".$row['atoc']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: `onClick='window.location.href='http://...` will this HTML code work? I always use `"` inside `'` (or vice versa)

Comment: Have you tried the code above ? Let me know if you got any issues.

Comment: Without the outer `'` it should be working (current version) - see http://jsfiddle.net/Ksqru/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using the heredoc method can sometimes be beneficial, since it parses the data inside pretty well, without having to add slashes to a lot of quotations.

I just created a test page on my server, which had the following code (Forgive the mess, but it would be easier if I had the database too, so instead, I just created an array for it to use.

```
<?php
$row = array
(
    'date'      => '12th jan', 
    'traction'  => 'None', 
    'start'     => 'now', 
    'end'       => 'an hour', 
    'fare1'     => '1.50', 
    'fare2'     => '2.95', 
    'book'      => 'google.com', 
    'atoc'      => 'cota'
);

$form = <<<FORM
    <tr>
        <td>{$row['date']}</td>
        <td>{$row['traction']}</td>
        <td>{$row['start']}</td>
        <td>{$row['end']}</td>
        <td>{$row['fare1']}</td>
        <td>{$row['fare2']}</td>
        <td><button onClick="document.location='http://www.{$row['book']}'">Button</button></td>
        <td>{$row['atoc']}</td>
    </tr>
FORM;
echo $form;
```

It's personal preference, but while I dislike using heredoc, I tend to use it when using JS inside html, with php variables too, as it just makes it quicker to write as I don't need to escape/concat half of the code I'm writing.

Hope this helps some.